# Where to get transparent assets to create top view scenes?

Tags: png, resource-recommendations, stock-images

I'm working for a client that really loves creating scenery using fern leaves, and flower petals and stuff like that for her product photography. I'm working on a website for her and on my proposal I'm thinking on adding small details like that to keep everything on brand. I've been looking all over and I can't seem to find a website to download or even buy this kind of assets, that would be normally used on mockups.

Here's an image in case anyone's not familiar with what I mean

[image]
[image]

I know I could probably find some stock images and delete the background in Photoshop, but I imagine someone knows where to find exactly what I'm looking for. Also, most stock images are not, for example, a single fern leaf but a bunch of them, on on top of the other.

Hopefully someone can help me!
Cheers

Comment: If you search for "watercolour foliage" on a stock art website you should find some. Adobe stock has many.

Comment: I'm voting to close as duplicate because for sure you'll be able to find these images in one of the stock services mentioned in the duplicate answer. In fact, just searching for "foliage" will bring many isolated images on Shutterstock for example

Comment: As explained on my original post, I'm looking for a specific service that offers the kind of assets that I'm looking for. I'm not asking for legal advice, nor I am not saying that stock photo websites don't have them. If searching for foliage in Shutterstock, iStock or any other service is the only way to go I'll accept it. But this question is specifically looking for a service that focuses on scenery assets, if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of imagery I would go to Freepik.com and filter on PSD images:

[Is this what you're looking for?](https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=leaf&sort=popular&type=psd)

Comment: Not quite but close enough. I'm actually looking for more realistic images, maybe cut outs from stock photos. This is a good temp solution, but I'm looking for something like pngtree, with more professional results. Thanks!

Comment: @Jose I checked Freepik again and it seems that the PSD filter has more realistic photos, and has a lot of quality cutouts which is what I think you're looking for. I updated the link above^